# How to use vertical align in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Simple problem: How do I vertically align a col within a col using bootstrap? Example here (I want to vertically align child1a and child1b):

http://bootply.com/73666

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12">

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 child1">
    <div class="col-12 child1a">Child content 1a</div>
    <div class="col-12 child1b">Child content 1b</div>

  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 child2">
  Child content 2<br>
  Child content 2<br>
  Child content 2<br>
  Child content 2<br>
  Child content 2<br>

  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Some CSS:

```
.col-lg-12{
top:40px;
bottom:0px;
border:4px solid green;


}

  .child1a, .child1b{
  border:4px solid black;
  display:inline-block !important;
}

.child1{
  border:4px solid blue;
  height:300px;
  display:table-cell !important;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.child2{
  border:4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: The solution provided in: **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3][1]** works great!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
.parent {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.child {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

`table-layout: fixed` prevents breaking the functionality of the col-* classes.

Comment: **table-layout:fixed**! That was the property I forgot to add. Without it, the table automatic layout will override the element width set by Bootstrap. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I had to add `float: none` to `.child`. Else `display` was considered as `block` no matter what (instead of `table-cell`). Weird, because every one seems happy with the proposed solution. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5, nothing fancy.

Comment: @philippe_b Had to do this as well. `float: center` implies `display: block` and I guess it took precedence over `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Also had to add a `float: none` to `.child` to make it work. Great job, btw. The only one that worked out for me after multiple highly-voted answers.

Answer (score 42):

Maybe an old topic but if someone needs further help with this do the following for example (this puts the text in middle line of image if it has larger height then the text).

HTML:

```
<div class="row display-table">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 display-cell">
        img
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 display-cell">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.display-table{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.display-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

The important thing that I missed out on was "float: none;" since it got float left from bootstrap col attributes.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks but using this example I see that column stacking stops working

Comment: but this solution is not responsive

Answer (score 8):

For the parent: `display: table;`

For the child: `display: table-cell;`

Then add `vertical-align: middle;`

I can make a fiddle but home time now, yay!

OK here is the lovely fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/AJAhR/

```
.parent {
   display:table;
}

.child {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: the question is about bootstrap grid views. How to include table , table-cell method without  breaking bootstrap grid operations.

Answer (score 6):

I had to add width: 100%; to display table to fix some strange bahavior in IE and FF, when i used this example. IE and FF had some problems displaying the col-md-* tags at the right width

```css
.display-table {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
}

.display-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
}
```

Comment: What example are you referring to here when you say "when i used this example."

Comment: Oh sorry, i wasn't able to add a comment to the reffered example... here my full code:
 .display-table {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .display-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
    }

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/zN39r/

HTML:

```
<div class="item row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><h4>This is some text.</h4></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"><h4>This is some more.</h4></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.item div h4 {
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Important notes:

- The `vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;` must be applied to a tag that has no Bootstrap classes applied; it cannot be a `col-*`, a `row`, etc.
- This can't be done without this extra, possibly pointless tag in your HTML, unfortunately.
- The backgrounds are unnecessary - they're just there for demo purposes. So, you don't need to apply any special rules to the `row` or `col-*` tags.
- It is important to notice the inner tag does not stretch to 100% of the width of its parent; in our scenario this didn't matter but it may to you. If it does, you end up with something closer to some of the other answers here:

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/zN39r/1/

CSS:

```
div.item div {
    background: #fdd;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: table;
}
div.item div h4 {
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;    
    display: table-cell;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Notice the added table-layout and display properties on the `col-*` tags. This must be applied to the tag(s) that have `col-*` applied; it won't help on other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Prinsen's answer is the best choice. But, to fix the issue where the columns don't collapse his code needs to be surrounded by a media check statement. This way these styles are only applied when the larger columns are active. Here is the updated complete answer.

HTML:

```
<div class="row display-table">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 display-cell">
        img
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 display-cell">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
   .display-table{
       display: table;
       table-layout: fixed;
   }

   .display-cell{
       display: table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle;
       float: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean you want *1b* and *1b* to be side by side?

```
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 child1">
      <div class="col-6 child1a">Child content 1a</div>
      <div class="col-6 child1b">Child content 1b</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: that would be horizontal not vertical align

Comment: but it is vertically align already? is it not? 1a is already above 1b

Comment: vertical align, so it is in the middle of the parent div with equal spacing above and below

Answer (score -3):

With Bootstrap 4, you can do it much more easily: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/#vertical-alignment