# vertically align span in bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have a bootstrap div with "row" class, and 2 divs inside acting as columns, A and B.

A contains a span with an icon. B contains a panel which height is variable, even after it loads, the user can add things to it and its height can still grow or become smaller.

I need to vertically center my span, taking the panel's height as reference.

here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"><span class="icon-clipboard icon-agenda-item"></span></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default deletable-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               heading content
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               body content
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

The first part is how it is displayed now, and the second part is how I want it to be displayed. As you can see, the "content" is editable inline, so if the panel grows, the span needs to adjust as well.

[image]

thank you very much!

**EDIT 1**
I must add that I am using IE.
I tried the first suggestion and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Those images look the same to me.

Comment: maybe this awnser on stack overflow will help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465825/vertical-align-middle-with-bootstrap-responsive-grid

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 v-align"><span class="icon-clipboard icon-agenda-item"></span></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 v-align">
        <div class="panel panel-default deletable-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               heading content
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               body content
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

where:

```
.v-align {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Please note, that both columns added, equals 11, instead of 12. There was the key! I don't know why, but if I left it 1 and 11 (resulting in 12 in total) it was displayed as mi edit image.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it, But you have to remove some bootstrap class and add two of your own class and you can set it easily. Here is the code

```css
.content{
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}
.a{
  display:inlin-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:20%;
}


.b{
  display:inlin-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="a">
      <span class="icon-clipboard icon-agenda-item"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        <div class="panel panel-default deletable-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               heading content
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               body content
            </div> 
        </div>  
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I hope This will help you

Regards,
Sarbasish

Comment: Thank you! but it still doesn't work, I will edit my question so you can see.

Comment: Actually What your did in your code. It will not work. If you replace the code with my code, Then it will work. you can set the width of a and b class and change according to screen size.