# Push column in a grid to the bottom, vertically align not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I have a 3 columns grid with 1st and 3rd columns having 3 rows but 2nd column only 1 row.

```
1.1    ==2==    3.1
1.2             3.2
1.3             3.3
```

How can I push the `==2==` to the bottom?

```
1.1             3.1
1.2             3.2
1.3    ==2==    3.3
```

Taking hints from 
[vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)
&
[How to use vertical align in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192114/how-to-use-vertical-align-in-bootstrap)
I make it into a table and cell format
but it's still not working...

http://jsfiddle.net/qfbp1o86/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `float:none` for your child element.

```
.child {
border: 1px dotted blue;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:bottom;
text-align:center;  
float:none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/qfbp1o86/1/)